# for loop to load multiple RData files

Tags: r, for-loop, rdata

I am new to R. I am trying to load multiple RData files from a single folder using a for-loop, however my below code only loads the last iteration. I am struggling to understand the issue, any solutions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
myfiles <- list.files("Data/","*.RData", full.names="TRUE")
for (i in 1:length(myfiles)) {
   load(myfiles[i])
}
```

Comment: Try `lapply(myfiles,load)`

Comment: Do the objects stored in your different RData files have the same name? If so, they will get replaced with each iteration, so only the last one stays in the environment

Comment: @Duck: This should not change anything or? Inside the lapply statement, it will basically execute the same things as in his for loop or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Julian_Hn As you said if the names are the same the files are being overwritten. Better trying creating a new list `List<-list()` and then `List <- lapply(myfiles,load)`

Comment: @Duck I was curious and tried your solution on some data of mine. This will just create a list, with the names of all the objects inside the files, not actually load the objects.

Comment: @teej have you looked at the object `myfiles` to make sure it contains what you think it contains?

Comment: @Duck: `List <- lapply(myfiles, function(fil) mget(load(fil)))` would work to actually load in the data sets into the list

Comment: @Julian_Hn Yes you were right, the function I was using was giving the data frame objects the same name.

Comment: @Duck Thank you,  List <- lapply(myfiles, function(fil) mget(load(fil))) did work, however I was trying to load the data frame objects into Power Bi and it didn't like this method. It was very useful though in helping me figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The data frame objects in each file were of the same name so it was getting replaced with each iteration.

I was using R script to load the data frames from each file into Power Bi. To do this I had to assign a different name to the data frame object on each iteration. The following solution uses the load.RData function to easily achieve this.

```
library(miceadds)
myfiles = list.files("Data/","*.RData", full.names="TRUE")
j <- 1
for (i in 1:length(myfiles)){
  load.Rdata(myfiles[i], "df")
  assign(paste("df", j, sep= ""),df)
  j = j+1
  load(myfiles[i])
}
rm(df)
```